# Http 401 entries in IIS log of SharePoint Server

Tags: wss-3.0, performance, permissions, 401

I am trying to fix a performance problem on a WSS 3.0 clustered site.

Each server has ca. 30000 requests per hour, but ca. 90% are of type:

> 2010-10-13 10:00:05 W3SVC14309999999
>   servername 10.192.63.112 GET
>   /sites/xxxx/_themes/Lacquer/viewheadergrad_lacquer.gif
>   - 80 - 10.192.39.141 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+HO32602R;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727)
>   MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie=80;+WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated=80
>   http://yyyy/sites/xxx/main.aspx ccccc
>   401 2 2148074254 291 521 15

Anyone know what could be generating these requests and why they are getting http 401.

**Edit**

We are trying to find out what authentication method is used, it is either NTLM or Kerberos in a Load Balanced environment.

**Edit 2**

There appears to be a pattern with 5 calls that return http 401.2, then 1 call that returns http 401.1, followed by a call that returns http 200.

**Edit 3**

We are using NTLM authentication

Comment: are users actually seeing an error?  Looks like a problem with anonymous access, do they have access to the layouts folder?

Comment: They are not seeing any errors, just that it is going really slow.

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of authentication you are using on this web app?  NTLM, Kerberos, Anonymouse, Forms-based, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by going over to kerberos authentication.